# How to get md5 of a file in s3 in node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, md5

I have a file in s3 where I want to get the base64 format of md5 without downloading the file to my local. I want to do this in node.js

Thanks.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't here to write your code for you. Show us what you've tried/researched already, and why whatever it is you've already tried/researched doesn't meet your requirements.

Comment: Are you saying that you want the MD5 of an object in Amazon S3 without having the actual contents of the S3 object? There is an `eTag` field that _typically_ contains the MD5 of the object (but it is a bit different with multi-part uploads). It is commonly used to verify that uploads were completed successfully. See: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/data-integrity-s3/

Answer (score 2):

A tiny bit of web searching reveals the [npm md5 module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/md5). You can the the hash of a file like this.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const md5 = require('md5')
 
fs.readFile('example.txt', function(err, buf) {
  console.log(md5(buf));
});
```

Or if you're using the aws s3 API, try this.

```
new AWS.S3().getObject({ Bucket: 'bucketname', Key: 'keyname' }, 
    function(err, data)
    {
      if (!err)
        console.log(md5(data.Body));
    });
```

**Pro tip**: When you want to do something like this, search for "nodejs whatever". Everybody's favorite search engine knows what to show you.

Comment: Thanks O.Jones. I want md5 in base64 format as mentioned. this gives me raw md5.

Comment: this worked for me 
 
const hash = md5Base64('my-plain-text-string');